# Vue.js (v3) use error component without changing URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I've been searching and tinkering for a while now without any luck. I'm looking to be able to catch errors and show an "Oops" page. Just to be clear, this isn't about 404 pages (which work fine).

I've reduced this for simplicity but in the below, before a page loads, it "attempts something which may fail". When that fails, I navigate to `/error` which shows an error page:

```js
const router = createRouter({ 
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Index
    },
    {
      path: '/something',
      component: Something
    },
    {
      path: '/error',
      component: Error
    },
    {
      path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
      component: NotFound
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  // attempt something which may fail
})

router.onError(() => router.push('/error'))
```

This all works fine, but it means that the `/error` path is navigable, and that a path change occurs. What I'd prefer is a way to be able to show an error component (`Error`) if an error occurs while keeping the url path the same.

Say I was on `/` and then I navigated to `/something` but "something failed", the url path would equal `/something` but the `Error` component would be used, rather than the `Something` component.

Any ideas? It seems like this should be manageable but so far I'm coming up blank.

Thanks

Comment: You can just use an overlay component to show your error. Control its show and hide status by vuex/pinia. Whenever you catch an error, instead of pushing the error page you can just set the show value of the error component to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Duannx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254681/duannx) commented above, a solution to this was to use a state to control this. Here's how I did it:

I created a Pinia store to hold an error variable:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useGlobalStore = defineStore({
  id: 'global',
  state: () => ({
    _error: false
  }),
  getters: {
    error: (state) => state._error
  },
  actions: {
    async setError(value) {
      this._error = !!value
    }
  }
})
```

In the router, I catch any errors:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { useGlobalStore } from '../stores/global'
import routes from './routes'

const history = createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL)
const router = createRouter({ history, routes })

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const globalStore = useGlobalStore()

  try {
    // Things which may fail here
    next()
  } catch (error) {
    globalStore.setError(true)
    return next()
  }
})

export default router
```

In the root component (`App.vue`), I then check for the error state, and either show that or the router view based on whether or not the error state is set the true.

```html
<template>
  <Error v-if="globalStore.error" />
  <RouterView v-else />
</template>
```

This works great, thanks Duannx.